# What exactly does isNaN() do in javaScript?

Tags: javascript, object, methods, numbers

`isNaN()` returns `false` if and only if the argument is number.

```
var a = new Number(1);
```

By doing so, `a` is an object now.
So why is `isNaN(a)` returning false?

Comment: `isNaN` returns true if and only if its argument is the value `NaN`.  It returns false in all other cases.

Comment: Are you having further issues moving on? If your problem is solved then you should mark the answer that helped resolving the problem as accepted. This helps other people to find what they are looking for. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 6):

`isNaN()` tests whether an input is **NOT** a number.

```
var a = new Number(1)
```

`a` is a number object. Therefore `isNaN()` returns `false`.

Here is a nice [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) containing `isNaN()` behaviors with different edge cases. Unfortunately some of them are not as intuitive as hoped, so it's worth reading.

Comment: _"should"_? `isNaN(new Number(1))` ___always___ returns `true`. (Unless the actual JavaScript interpreter is messed with)

Comment: good point. I rephrased it to be more authoritative.

Answer (score 2):

The global `isNaN()` function coerces its argument to a number value before testing for `NaN`.  Your object converts cleanly to the number `1`, and `1` is not `NaN`.

Note that `isNaN("1")` also returns false, because the string `"1"` converts cleanly to a number that isn't `NaN`.

The `isNaN` function is not really intended as a general-purpose test for whether something is or is not a number. It's a test for the specific numeric value `NaN`. It's often used as a general-purpose test, and that (mostly) works because JavaScript returns `NaN` when an attempt to convert a value to a number fails. That's somewhat impure, because `NaN` exists as a marker with a specific purpose in the floating point system.

Some JavaScript environments have `Number.isNaN()` in addition to the global `isNaN`. The function on the Number constructor does not perform a type coercion first. For that reason, `Number.isNaN("foo")` returns `false`, because even though the string `"foo"` cannot be converted to a number cleanly, it's not the constant `NaN`.